# Obtain enterprise WSDL via curl

Tags: oauth2, wsdl, curl

I am trying to obtain enterprise WSDL by accessing 
https://cs15.salesforce.com/soap/wsdl.jsp?type=* URL via curl.
For this, I have obtained access token through OAUTH2 method via the following curl command.

```
​curl https://cs15.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d ‘grant_type=password -d client_id=myclientid -d client_secret=mysecret -d username=myname@domain.com -d password=mypassword
```

Next I used the access token in following curl command to obtain WSDL

```
curl https://cs15.salesforce.com/soap/wsdl.jsp?type=* -H "Cookie: sid=myaccesstoken"
```

But response from above curl command indicates that I was getting redirected to Salesforce login page instead of WSDL page.

1. I have validated my approach by taking “sid” value from web browser cookies after successfully logging into Salesforce, used it in the above curl and it worked as I expected.
2. I have also tried using the access token which I got through OAUTH2 method in REST API requests and they worked as expected. Hence I assume the access token via OAuth is valid.

Appreciate if someone can advise why I am not getting WSDL page or suggest me an alternate approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem could be that you were using an access token instead of a session id. I just got it to work by logging in through the enterprise api and using that session id for `sid=` in the header.

the command I used to log in and get the session id:

```
$ curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/33.0 -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8' -H 'SOAPAction: login' -d @login
```

the file **login**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
        <n1:login xmlns:n1="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
            <n1:username>USERNAME</n1:username>
            <n1:password>PASSWORD</n1:password>
        </n1:login>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the example. I was able to successfully get session id and use it to get WSDL.

Answer (score 1):

What OAuth [scopes](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_scopes.htm&language=en_US) did you specify for your connected app?
[image]

These should appear directly below the Consumer Key and Consumer Secret for the Connected App.

I suspect that without either the `full` or `web` scopes the Session Id won't be valid for what is essentially functionality that a web browser would perform. That the curl request works with a session id taken from the browsers sid cookie supports this.

Alternatively, you could use the credentials against either the Partner or Enterprise SOAP APIs to establish a full session.

Comment: Interesting idea. The `sid=` in the header makes me think that there is a possibility that there is a validation in place where the system will only accept a Session Id. It would be interesting to see if changing the scope of access provided by the Access Token would work here.

Comment: @martin The access token and session id are fully interchangeable **if** the access token was created with the `full` scope. You'll notice that they have the same format. They will all appear under "Session Management" in the setup pages.

Comment: @DanielBallinger OAuth scope wasn't Full when I lodged my question. Nevertheless changing to Full access as you suggested did not solve the problem (though I was positive it would). For now I will settle with idea of obtaining session Id through SOAP API. Thanks for your suggestion.